# After upgrade to php 8.1, sqlsrv pdo drivers not found

Tags: php, pdo, sqlsrv, php-8

After upgrade to php 8.1  (Linux PHP) , Azure webapp does not seems to have driver for MS SQL. It was OK with php 7.4.

Following this guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git?tabs=cli), steps to build and configure Azure App service was:
az appservice plan create -g rg-MyResourceG -n MyPlan --is-linux
az webapp create -g rg-MyResource --plan MyPlan --name MyApp --% --runtime "PHP|7.4" --deployment-local-git
Change to PHP 8.1 following this guide: https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/Runtime_Support/php_support.md
az webapp config appsettings set --name MyApp --resource-group MyResourceG --settings DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH='main'
on my local server: php artisan key:generate --show
az webapp config appsettings set --name Glados9L --resource-group rg-blueprism-tst --settings APP_KEY="Output from last command" APP_DEBUG="true"
git remote add glados9l https://MyUser@MyApp.scm.azurewebsites.net/MyApp.git
git push glados9l main
...........
remote: Done in 223 sec(s).
remote:
remote: Removing existing manifest file
remote: Creating a manifest file...
remote: Manifest file created.
remote: Copying .ostype to manifest output directory.
remote:
remote: Done in 457 sec(s).
remote: Running post deployment command(s)...
remote:
remote: Generating summary of Oryx build
remote: Parsing the build logs
remote: Found 0 issue(s)
remote:
remote: Build Summary :
remote: ===============
remote: Errors (0)
remote: Warnings (0)
remote:
remote: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
remote: Deployment successful. deployer =  deploymentPath =
remote: Deployment Logs : 'https://glados9l.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui/jsonviewer?view_url=/api/deployments/ef2b3e8ce9341d66fa5e64826721e09085dbe214/log'
To https://myplan.scm.azurewebsites.net/Glados9L.git

- [new branch]      main -> main

```
root@9dcf7762daa9:/home# php -i | grep sqlsrv
Cannot load Zend OPcache - it was already loaded
root@9dcf7762daa9:/home# odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
root@9dcf7762daa9:/home# php -v
Cannot load Zend OPcache - it was already loaded
PHP 8.1.6 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2022 07:43:32) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.6, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
root@9dcf7762daa9:/home#
```

Comment: You'll need to provide some more details about your installation before anyone can help you with this - how did you build this server? how did you configure it? how did you upgrade it to PHP 8.1? You can also look for relevant information in `php -i` (which is the same as running `phpinfo()` in a CLI script) - is it loading the config files you think it should be?

Comment: IMSop, Many thanks for feedback and questions. 
Befor answer questions, I would say again that It works very well (PHP 7.4) before upgrade to PHP 8.1. And 
1- If you mean Azure App service, It was build by command.
2- upgrade from php 7.4 to 8.1 from Azure portal and then push my Laravel app (that was upgraded from 8 to 9 and works very well on local server) by git push again.
3- You write run "php -i" ( I have already phpinfo(); runnung on this Azureapp) and can see the output page, but can not understand which config file, I must look after? again many thanks for feedback

Comment: "It was build by command" - what command? where? Remember that we aren't looking over your shoulder, and things that seem really obvious to you because you do them every day are complete unknowns to us. You need to be really specific about what tools you're using, so that people can understand your situation.

Comment: Please click [edit] and add details, properly formatted, to the question itself. This comment section is just for quick temporary notes, and doesn't support formatting or long text.

Comment: Has edited question and updated with detailed steps about built and configure it and push php application(Laravel 9) to.

Answer (score 2):

It is a known issue that pdo_sqlsrv is missing in PHP 8.1 image and according to [this pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/pull/1623), they are adding this driver soon.

As for now, you can download and enable it manually by following [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1063154/pdo-sqlsrv-drivers-is-not-found-after-update-of-ph.html)

Comment: Yes, and many thanks for reply and I get this support from M. S. last week and it is done now.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1063154/pdo-sqlsrv-drivers-is-not-found-after-update-of-ph.html?childToView=1063253#answer-1063253

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. My app was working perfectly for a few years. After switching the azure webapp from PHP7.4 to PHP8, the connection with the SQL server fail. (PHP7.4 is depreciated soon)

I get this error message on when I connect to the page with my browser.

> Error connedmg to SOL Server PDOException Obred ( [message protected] => could not find driver [string Excephorrpnvate]=> [code protected] => 0 [file protected] -> ihome/siteAmwroot/DEV railtypeWrthProcess php [line protected] => 122 [trace Exception pnvate]=> Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => /home/site/wwwroot/DEVraillypeWith Process php [line] => 122 [function] -> construct [class] => POO [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] sglsry server - lcp delachauxrailtechbddserver database windows net,1433, Database = BDDWeldingKrtAPP [1] => weldingKrtApp01 [2] => ****** ) ) ) [previous Exception pnvate]=> [errorInfo] ) 1

Here how I connect to the server with PHP.

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server = tcp:delachauxrailtechbddserver.database.windows.net,1433; Database = BDDWeldingKitAPP", "weldingKitApp01", "******");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print("Error connecting to SQL Server.");
    die(print_r($e));
}
```

The webapp was created using the Azure console interface. Not with command.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score -1):

The same thing happened to me the solution:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername,$port;Database=$database;ConnectionPooling=0", $username, $password);
  // php 7 ,array(
  //   PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
  //   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
  // )
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);//php 8
```